# MySql and inserting last ID problem remains

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Ok after much reading and trying I still cant seem to get this to work:

```
      OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES ('rusty@msn.com'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", cn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                string theUserId = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                Label10.Text = theUserId;
```

Tables:

```
User
--------
UserID (auto increment, pk)
Email
```

Running in debug mode I get errors on this line,

```
            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

and,

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Mysql is saying its a syntax error on this line `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"`, cn); but from what ive read this is legal.

Exact Error:

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.9]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1
```

**EDIT: Justins method:**

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
{
    // ODBC command and transaction objects
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
    OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

    // tell the command to use our connection
    command.Connection = connection;

    try
    {
        // open the connection
        connection.Open();

        // start the transaction
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        // TODO: Build a SQL INSERT statement
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "')", connection); 

        // run the insert using a non query call
        command.CommandText = cmd.ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        /* now we want to make a second call to MYSQL to get the new index 
           value it created for the primary key.  This is called using scalar so it will
            return the value of the SQL  statement.  We convert that to an int for later use.*/
        command.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
        id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

        // the name id doesnt not exist in the current context

        // Commit the transaction.
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label10.Text = ": " + ex.Message;

        try
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to perform 2 queries / statements in 1 `OdbcCommand`? What happens if you do it in 2 separate ones?

Comment: @Wrikken, that is the problem, the .net mySQL ODBC driver doesn't allow multiple commands in that context.  You have to make two separate calls.  I've run into this issue before ;)

Comment: Try using a string instead of creating another OdbcCommand object with the string and connection parameters.  Then set the command.CommandText to that String.  I think some odd things are happening when you create a second OdbcCommand object.

Answer (score 4):

Clarification, the mySQL .net ODBC driver doesn't allow multiple commands to be run like you are describing. You have to make two separate calls and wrap them in a transaction.

```
// open a new connection using a default connection string I have defined elsewhere
using( OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection( s_connectionString ) )
{
      // ODBC command and transaction objects
      OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
      OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

      // tell the command to use our connection
      command.Connection = connection;

      try
      {
           // open the connection
           connection.Open();

           // start the transaction
           transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

           // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
           command.Connection = connection;
           command.Transaction = transaction;

           // TODO: Build a SQL INSERT statement
           StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder();

           // run the insert using a non query call
           command.CommandText = SQL.ToString();
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();

           /* now we want to make a second call to MYSQL to get the new index 
              value it created for the primary key.  This is called using scalar so it will
               return the value of the SQL  statement.  We convert that to an int for later use.*/
           command.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
           id = Convert.ToInt32( command.ExecuteScalar() );

           // Commit the transaction.
           transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch( Exception ex )
     {
          Debug.WriteLine( ex.Message );

          try
          {
               // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
               transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch
            {
                 // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
              }
         }
}
```

Comment: i get an error: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.9]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If your Email is unique you can use

```
Select ID From User where Email='rusty@msn.com'
```

you are sure that always you get the answer right.

If your Email is not unique you should use lock to make sure that only on thread is executing query and then use this query after your insert

```
Select Max(ID) From User
```

Comment: ahh sorry the email was just an example I wont know the email untill its inserted into the db hence why i need last transaction

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

1. Add an out param to your query:
2. inside the query use SET @OpParam = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
3. In your code get it as if ((int)@OpParam.Value > 0){ pull out  }.
4. Also, if run select then instead NonQuery, use ExecuteScalar().

Hope it might help you.

Comment: executescalar is used for the select. tryed setting an out param still no joy

Comment: you can also use with insert, update delete or multiple statments , if you need to retrieve th value of very first cell

Comment: If you are returning identity and need it on your code, then you need ExecuteScalar, instead of NonQuery as Non Query will give you th number of rows affected by the query.