# convert commandtext to string problem in answered question

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Question Related to this post, I think he is offline though so I can't get any feedback atm:

[MySql and inserting last ID problem remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542999/mysql-and-inserting-last-id-problem-remains)

I'm not sure if I'm being completely blind but in this code:

```
// run the insert using a non query call
command.CommandText = cmd.ToString();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

/* now we want to make a second call to MYSQL to get the new index 
   value it created for the primary key.  This is called using scalar so it will
    return the value of the SQL  statement.  We convert that to an int for later use.*/
command.CommandText = "select last_insert_id();";
id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

//------- the name id does not exist in the current context

// Commit the transaction.
transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  Label10.Text = ": " + ex.Message;

  try {
    // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
    transaction.Rollback();
  } catch {
    // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
  }
}
}
```

ID isn't set to anything and I'm not sure how he was trying to set it to the last inserted id?

**EDIT: **

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Label10.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return the id of the inserted record using `select @@IDENTITY;` without having to use a second query:

```
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES ('rusty@msn.com'); select @@IDENTITY;"
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

After reviewing your old question, this should work the same:

```
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES ('rusty@msn.com'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: omg this worked I tryed this but with String.Format duhh, but the problem is now with what was returned, I set it to a label and I get 0 returned?

Comment: which isnt what its stored as, mysql says that it will return the AI primarykey which is UserID in my User table?

Comment: ahhh wait no i forgot the select statement at the end tryed it with the select Last inserted and again I get the same error so looks like Justin might be right